# Postgresql: increment column with unique values without constraint violation?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I am trying to implement a table with revision history in Postgresql as follows:

- table has a multi-column primary key or unique constraint on columns `id` and `rev` (both numeric)
- to create a new entry, insert data, have `id` auto-generated and `rev` set to 0
- to update an existing entry, insert a new row with the previous `id` and `rev` set to -1, then increment the `rev` on all entries with that `id` by 1
- to get the latest version, select by `id` and `rev = 0`

The problem that I am facing is the update after the insert; unsurprisingly, Postgresql sometimes raises a "duplicate key" error when rows are updated in the wrong order.

Since there is no `ORDER BY` available on `UPDATE`, I searched for other solutions and noticed that the updates pass without errors if the starting point is the result set of an subquery:

```
UPDATE test
  SET rev = test.rev + 1
FROM (
  SELECT rev
    FROM test 
  WHERE id = 99
  ORDER BY rev DESC
) AS prev
WHERE test.rev = prev.rev
```

The descending order ensures that the greater values get incremented first, so that the lower values do not violate the unique constraint when they get updated.

One catch though; I can't derive from the documentation if this is working due to some implementation detail (which might change without notice in the future) or indeed guaranteed by the language specification - can someone explain?

I was also wondering whether it is performance-wise better to have the `rev` column in the index (as described above, which leads to at least a partial index rebuild on every update, but maybe also to faster reads) or to define a (non-unique) index on `id` only and ignore the performance impact that could be caused by an (initially) larger query set. (I am expecting a rather low revision count per unique `id` on average, maybe 5.)

Comment: See `DEFERRABLE` here [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). Though to me it seem easier to have an insert timestamp and use that to distinguish versions.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the hint with `DEFERRABLE`, sounds great, will look into that. About the timestamp: I was hoping that it would simplify queries and improve performance to select for `rev = 0` instead of evaluating MAX(timestamp). Does that make sense or is the aggregation common/neglectible?

Comment: Every time you update the `rev` besides rewriting the table you will be rewriting the index. Not exactly a performance enhancer.